# What are minimal compilations steps to start new simulation after changing some file?

Tags: vhdl, intel-fpga

This question is about Altera Quartus. Suppose I have a bdf file with few entities. Each entity has it's own VHDL file. I found a bug in one of entities and fixed it (edited a vhdl file). What are minimal compilations steps to start a new simulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how clever the compiler is.

If your `entity` and `architecture` are in the same file, then in most cases recompiling the `architecture` will also "touch" the entity, which means that any `architecture` which instantiates that `entity` will also need to be recompiled (and so on up).

If you split the `entity` out into a separate file, then (assuming you only make changes to the `architecture`) you only have to recompile the file with the `architecture` in.  I used to do this all the time in development to speed the compile/simulate/edit cycle.

(You're using Qurtus I see, but with Modelsim you can pass a `-just a` switch to make it only compile `architecture`s and this achieves the same without splitting things out into multiple files.  There may be something you can do with Quartus to get it to behave similarly)